# Someone please explain this phrase for me? "Non-vital capacity"

Tags: meaning

> In accordance with the Technological Clearances Act, we’ll set you up
>   in a new non-vital capacity and confiscate your classified research.

Thank you so much.

Comment: It means you will be transferred to a job that is not considered critical or essential to the mission of the organization, and given duties that do not involve classified information. This is a major demotion. Presumably, either the person misused classified information, or it was discovered that they did not have proper security clearance to be working with classified information.  It sounds like the professional equivalent of being "sent to Siberia". It's what they might do if you deserve to be fired, but for some reason you cannot be fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means **the person in question will be given a new position or role ("capacity") that is of no great importance ("non-vital").** In essence, the person in question in being demoted.

Capacity:

> The position in which one functions; role

(American Heritage Dictionary)

Vital:

> extremely important and necessary for something to succeed or exist

(Longman)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.